# How do I set the stroke color for column charts within IcCube

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I'm looking for a way to not only draw a fill color for my column chart, but also set it's stroke so I can have a border for each slice. This would look good for forecasts / actuals comparisons, like this example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully grasp your question, but to create such a chart in icCube, you'll need to use the chart/Type: Combo and combine several column graphs.

assumption: account is an expense account

In this case:

1. first column, data: actuals, color red, miscellaneous: new stack = on
2. second column (will plot over the 1st): data: budget/forecast, color: conditional - if it's in the future > white, else it is green, set the linecolor & thickness, miscellaneous: new stack = on
3. third column: (will plot over the 1st and 2nd): data: min(actuals & budget/forecast), color: grey

[image]

Comment: This is spot on, thank you! The main issue I had was that I cannot find a way to set the border/line thickness as displayed in the chart above, where you use empty columns with a black border to indicate that those values are forecasts only - and of course how you would highlight the current week (as shown in blue)

Comment: Great. If this answered your question, could you tag it as 'answered'? Wrt the highlight, I assumed you took a screenprint from the dashboard from the finance demo on the inside vision website. So, the blue highlight is a result of the 'Cursor' setting in the chart. If you are looking to set a 'Guide' showing the last period, please raise another question, I might have a solution to that.

Comment: And how do you set the stroke Color (in the Finance Demo, those are the black bordered column with white filling)

Comment: That's in point #2; you just set the line color and line thickness. I've included a screenprint.